# .htaccess 301 redirect not working correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup an .htaccess file to redirect old urls which I have REMOVED the pages from the server (not sure if this is the problem). I'm trying to redirect the pages to the new page which has the same content. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work? (I believe it should) followed several online guides.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/wheels_landing_page.php [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/wheels_landing_page.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/wheelsLanding.php/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/dealerships.php [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/dealerships.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/contact.php/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wheels_landing_page\.php(.*)$ http://example.com/wheelsLanding.php$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^dealerships\.php(.*)$ http://example.com/contact.php$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, could you explain quickly what you did differently? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, the file part of the url is not in the `HTTP_HOST` (only the domain name `www.example.com`). I test after this part with `RewriteRule`. And I have combined the 2 test for domain with or without `www` in one test.